# App product listing id in google marketplace

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

With recent changes to listing an app on google marketplace, i am wondering how to get a product listing id of an app that is not searchable yet. Our is enterprise app installable by domain administrators only. Initially, we want make it available to our users via a link. The chrome webstore item id doesn't work in app marketplace and app is not installable from chrome  webstore. It is treated as chrome extension and handled as such. Appreciate any help in this regard.

Thanks.